# How to calculate Percentage in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection in that collection **UPSTempStatus** field. These field is in arrayIndex format. Collection sample as follows

```
  { 
    "_id" : ObjectId("576165f58d8b8f39458b456c"), 
    "EventTS" : ISODate("2016-06-07T03:30:00.000+0000"), 
    "UPSTempStatus" : [
       NumberInt(1), 
       NumberInt(2), 
       null, 
       NumberInt(0), 
       null
     ], 
    "TempStatus" : [
       NumberInt(1), 
       null, 
       NumberInt(1), 
       null, 
       null
    ], 
    "UPSStatus" : [
       NumberInt(1), 
       null, 
       NumberInt(1)
    ]
```

}

This is my sample of collection one record. Basically I want calculate percentage of UPSTempStatus. For that I create one query to calculate percentage my query as follows

```
    db.PMS.aggregate(
    {
        $project:{
            UPSTempStatus:1
        } 
    },
    { 
        $unwind : "$UPSTempStatus" 
    },
    {   
        $match: 
        {
            UPSTempStatus: {$ne:null} 
        } 
    },
    {   
        $group : { 
            _id:null, 
            totalcount : {$sum:1},
            LowTemp: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",0]},1,0]
                    }},
            HighTemp: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",2]},1,0]
                    }},
            NormalTemp: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",1]},1,0]
                    }},
            Error4: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",4]},1,0]
                    }},
            Error5: {
                $sum:{
                    $cond:[{$eq:["$UPSTempStatus",5]},1,0]
                    }},
    }},
    {$project:
    {
        LowTempPer:{ 
            $multiply:[{ $divide: ["$LowTemp","$totalcount"]},100]
        } , 
        NormalTempPer:{ 
            $multiply:[{ $divide: ["$NormalTemp","$totalcount"]},100]
        },
        HighTempPer:{ 
            $multiply:[{ $divide: ["$HighTemp","$totalcount"]},100]
        }
    }} ,
    {$sort: {_id:-1}}
);
```

This query give proper output but take time to calculate percentage. Can I create more better query to calculate percentage? If yes, so please suggest me how to create better query?

Comment: Formatting the code properly increases its readabaility and, therefore, chance of getting an answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i formatting the code please check.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev i made changes in question and code also.

Comment: Too much formatting now :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev any other process to more simplify above query. Please suggest me.

Comment: could you tell us how the data is stored? Is array position connected with a special reading type/value?